# Swapping the first value of a dynamic array with the maximum without changing the order of the rest

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I've made a little program where i input a dimension of an array and then i fill it with values, then i tried to add a function where the first value of the array gets swapped with the biggest one, the problem i have is that all the other values (if we are considering that they are bigger than the first one) get swapped aswell in the process of the cycle, how do i avoid that?

```
void maxVectorSwap(int *v, int dim){
int i;
int app;
int max=0;
for(i=0;i<dim;i++){    
    max=v[0];
    if(v[i]>max){
        app=v[0];
        v[0]=v[i];
        v[i]=app;

    }   
}

printf("----------\n");
for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
    printf("v[%d]=%d\n",i,v[i]);                                       
}
printf("----------\n");  
}
```

Let's say i input the dimension of the array to be **5** and the values to be:

> **3 5 1 7 2**

The result i get with this function is:

> **7 3 1 5 2**

Which gives away that there more swaps, what i want instead is just to see 7 and 3 swapped so it would look like this:

> **7 5 1 3 2**

Comment: Two steps: 1) Find the maximum and its index. 2) Swap. Don't mix.

Comment: Totally forgot that i could use the index, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve this problem, lets look back at what our approach should be.

Problem: Swapping the maximum and the first indexed number.

Algorithm: To find where the maximum number is located and then swap the values using their indices.
Thus try to find the index first and then try swapping.

Updated Code:

```
void maxVectorSwap(int *v, int dim)
{
    int i;
    int app;

    //Lets assume the first element is the largerst number i.e index=0
    int indexOfMax=0;

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {    
        if(v[i]>v[indexOfMax])
        {
            indexOfMax=i;
            // store the updated maximum index in m
        }   
    }

    // now indexOfMax stores the location of the maximum number
    //Thus swapping now
    int temp=v[0];
    v[0]=v[indexOfMax];
    v[indexOfMax]=temp;

    printf("----------\n");
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
        printf("v[%d]=%d\n",i,v[i]);                                       
    }
    printf("----------\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void maxVectorSwap( int *v, size_t dim )
{
    size_t max_i = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < dim; i++ )
    {
        if ( v[max_i] < v[i] )  max_i = i; 
    }

    if ( max_i != 0 )
    {
        int tmp = v[0];
        v[0] = v[max_i];
        v[max_i] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 3, 5, 1, 7, 2 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    maxVectorSwap( a, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 5 1 7 2 
7 5 1 3 2
```